# upgraded to PHP 7 from 5 using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I was receiving an error message because I upgraded to PHP 7 from 5 and added public function helper(heler = array())    but now I receiving a parse error
Message: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

I have tried moving the array to the My_loader.php file but I receive the same error

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class MX_Loader extends CI_Loader {


protected $_module;

public $_ci_plugins = array();
public $_ci_cached_vars = array();

public function __construct() {

  parent::__construct();

  /* set the module name */
  $this->_module = CI::$APP->router->fetch_module();

  /* add this module path to the loader variables */
  $this->_add_module_paths($this->_module);
}

/** Initialize the module **/
public function _init($controller) {

  /* references to ci loader variables */
  foreach (get_class_vars('CI_Loader') as $var => $val) {
    if ($var != '_ci_ob_level') $this->$var =& CI::$APP->load->$var;
  }

  /* set a reference to the module controller */
  $this->controller = $controller;
  $this->__construct();
}

/** Add a module path loader variables **/
public function _add_module_paths($module = '') {

  if (empty($module)) return;

  foreach (Modules::$locations as $location => $offset) {

    /* only add a module path if it exists */
    if (is_dir($module_path = $location.$module.'/')) {
      array_unshift($this->_ci_model_paths, $module_path);
    }
  }
}

/** Load a module config file **/
public function config($file = 'config', $use_sections = FALSE, $fail_gracefully = FALSE) {
  return CI::$APP->config->load($file, $use_sections, $fail_gracefully, $this->_module);
}

/** Load the database drivers **/
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL) {

  if (class_exists('CI_DB', FALSE) AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset(CI::$APP->db) AND is_object(CI::$APP->db))
    return;

  require_once BASEPATH.'database/DB'.EXT;

  if ($return === TRUE) return DB($params, $active_record);

  CI::$APP->db = DB($params, $active_record);

  return CI::$APP->db;
}

/** Load a module helper **/
public function helper($helper) {

  if (is_array($helper)) return $this->helpers($helper);

  if (isset($this->_ci_helpers[$helper])) return;

  list($path, $_helper) = Modules::find($helper.'_helper', $this->_module, 'helpers/');

  if ($path === FALSE) return parent::helper($helper);

  Modules::load_file($_helper, $path);
  $this->_ci_helpers[$_helper] = TRUE;
}

/** Load an array of helpers **/
public function helpers($helpers) {
  foreach ($helpers as $_helper) $this->helper($_helper);
}

/** Load a module language file **/
public function language($langfile, $idiom = '', $return = FALSE, $add_suffix = TRUE, $alt_path = '') {
  return CI::$APP->lang->load($langfile, $idiom, $return, $add_suffix, $alt_path, $this->_module);
}

public function languages($languages) {
  foreach($languages as $_language) $this->language($language);
}

/** Load a module library **/
public function library($library, $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL) {

  if (is_array($library)) return $this->libraries($library);

  $class = strtolower(end(explode('/', $library)));
    public function helper($helper = array())
  if (isset($this->_ci_classes[$class]) AND $_alias = $this->_ci_classes[$class])
    return CI::$APP->$_alias;

  ($_alias = strtolower($object_name)) OR $_alias = $class;

  list($path, $_library) = Modules::find($library, $this->_module, 'libraries/');

  /* load library config file as params */
  if ($params == NULL) {
    list($path2, $file) = Modules::find($_alias, $this->_module, 'config/');
    ($path2) AND $params = Modules::load_file($file, $path2, 'config');
  }

  if ($path === FALSE) {

    $this->_ci_load_class($library, $params, $object_name);
    $_alias = $this->_ci_classes[$class];

  } else {

    Modules::load_file($_library, $path);

    $library = ucfirst($_library);
    CI::$APP->$_alias = new $library($params);

    $this->_ci_classes[$class] = $_alias;
  }

  return CI::$APP->$_alias;
  }

/** Load an array of libraries **/
public function libraries($libraries) {
  foreach ($libraries as $_library) $this->library($_library);
}

/** Load a module model **/
public function model($model, $object_name = NULL, $connect = FALSE) {

  if (is_array($model)) return $this->models($model);

  ($_alias = $object_name) OR $_alias = end(explode('/', $model));

  if (in_array($_alias, $this->_ci_models, TRUE))
    return CI::$APP->$_alias;

  /* check module */
  list($path, $_model) = Modules::find(strtolower($model), $this->_module, 'models/');

  if ($path == FALSE) {

    /* check application & packages */
    parent::model($model, $object_name);

  } else {

    class_exists('CI_Model', FALSE) OR load_class('Model', 'core');

    if ($connect !== FALSE AND ! class_exists('CI_DB', FALSE)) {
      if ($connect === TRUE) $connect = '';
      $this->database($connect, FALSE, TRUE);
    }

    Modules::load_file($_model, $path);

    $model = ucfirst($_model);
    CI::$APP->$_alias = new $model();

    $this->_ci_models[] = $_alias;
  }

  return CI::$APP->$_alias;
}

/** Load an array of models **/
public function models($models) {
  foreach ($models as $_model) $this->model($_model);
}

/** Load a module controller **/
public function module($module, $params = NULL) {

  if (is_array($module)) return $this->modules($module);

  $_alias = strtolower(end(explode('/', $module)));
  CI::$APP->$_alias = Modules::load(array($module => $params));
  return CI::$APP->$_alias;
}

/** Load an array of controllers **/
public function modules($modules) {
  foreach ($modules as $_module) $this->module($_module);
}

/** Load a module plugin **/
public function plugin($plugin) {

  if (is_array($plugin)) return $this->plugins($plugin);

  if (isset($this->_ci_plugins[$plugin]))
    return;

  list($path, $_plugin) = Modules::find($plugin.'_pi', $this->_module, 'plugins/');

  if ($path === FALSE) return;

  Modules::load_file($_plugin, $path);
  $this->_ci_plugins[$plugin] = TRUE;
}

/** Load an array of plugins **/
public function plugins($plugins) {
  foreach ($plugins as $_plugin) $this->plugin($_plugin);
}

/** Load a module view **/
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
  list($path, $view) = Modules::find($view, $this->_module, 'views/');
  $this->_ci_view_path = $path;
  return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}

public function _ci_is_instance() {}

public function _ci_get_component($component) {
  return CI::$APP->$component;
}

public function __get($class) {
  return (isset($this->controller)) ? $this->controller->$class : CI::$APP->$class;
}

public function _ci_load($_ci_data) {

  foreach (array('_ci_view', '_ci_vars', '_ci_path', '_ci_return') as $_ci_val) {
    $$_ci_val = ( ! isset($_ci_data[$_ci_val])) ? FALSE : $_ci_data[$_ci_val];
  }

  if ($_ci_path == '') {
    $_ci_file = strpos($_ci_view, '.') ? $_ci_view : $_ci_view.EXT;
    $_ci_path = $this->_ci_view_path.$_ci_file;
  } else {
    $_ci_file = end(explode('/', $_ci_path));
  }

  if ( ! file_exists($_ci_path))
    show_error('Unable to load the requested file: '.$_ci_file);

  if (is_array($_ci_vars))
    $this->_ci_cached_vars = array_merge($this->_ci_cached_vars, $_ci_vars);

  extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);

  ob_start();

  if ((bool) @ini_get('short_open_tag') === FALSE AND CI::$APP->config->item('rewrite_short_tags') == TRUE) {
    echo eval('?>'.preg_replace("/;*\s*\?>/", "; ?>", str_replace('<?=', '<?php echo ', file_get_contents($_ci_path))));
  } else {
    include($_ci_path);
  }

  log_message('debug', 'File loaded: '.$_ci_path);

  if ($_ci_return == TRUE) return ob_get_clean();

  if (ob_get_level() > $this->_ci_ob_level + 1) {
    ob_end_flush();
  } else {
    CI::$APP->output->append_output(ob_get_clean());
  }
}

/** Autoload module items **/
public function _autoloader($autoload) {

  $path = FALSE;

  if ($this->_module) {

    list($path, $file) = Modules::find('constants', $this->_module, 'config/');

    /* module constants file */
    if ($path != FALSE) {
      include_once $path.$file.EXT;
    }

    list($path, $file) = Modules::find('autoload', $this->_module, 'config/');

    /* module autoload file */
    if ($path != FALSE) {
      $autoload = array_merge(Modules::load_file($file, $path, 'autoload'), $autoload);
    }
  }

  /* nothing to do */
  if (count($autoload) == 0) return;

  /* autoload package paths */
  if (isset($autoload['packages'])) {
    foreach ($autoload['packages'] as $package_path) {
      $this->add_package_path($package_path);
    }
  }

  /* autoload config */
  if (isset($autoload['config'])) {
    foreach ($autoload['config'] as $config) {
      $this->config($config);
    }
  }

  /* autoload helpers, plugins, languages */
  foreach (array('helper', 'plugin', 'language') as $type) {
    if (isset($autoload[$type])){
      foreach ($autoload[$type] as $item) {
        $this->$type($item);
      }
    }
  }

  /* autoload database & libraries */
  if (isset($autoload['libraries'])) {
    if (in_array('database', $autoload['libraries'])) {
      /* autoload database */
      if ( ! $db = CI::$APP->config->item('database')) {
        $db['params'] = 'default';
        $db['active_record'] = TRUE;
      }
      $this->database($db['params'], FALSE, $db['active_record']);
      $autoload['libraries'] = array_diff($autoload['libraries'], array('database'));
    }

    /* autoload libraries */
    foreach ($autoload['libraries'] as $library) {
      $this->library($library);
    }
  }

  /* autoload models */
  if (isset($autoload['model'])) {
    foreach ($autoload['model'] as $model => $alias) {
      (is_numeric($model)) ? $this->model($alias) : $this->model($model, $alias);
    }
  }

  /* autoload module controllers */
  if (isset($autoload['modules'])) {
    foreach ($autoload['modules'] as $controller) {
      ($controller != $this->_module) AND $this->module($controller);
    }
  }
}
}

/** load the CI class for Modular Separation **/
(class_exists('CI', FALSE)) OR require dirname(__FILE__).'/Ci.php';
```

Comment: You are in dire need of code review. As far as this question goes, it would be much simpler if you posted only the piece of code where the error happens and also paste in the the full error message as appears on your screen.

Comment: I believe that you either made a mistake while pasting or have a syntax error here: `public function helper($helper = array())`

Comment: PD of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18050071) (almost closed now anyway)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an extra line just pasted into the middle of the code at line 105:

```
  $class = strtolower(end(explode('/', $library)));
    public function helper($helper = array()) // <===== delete this one
  if (isset($this->_ci_classes[$class]) AND $_alias = $this->_ci_classes[$class])
    return CI::$APP->$_alias;
```

If you run `php -l <file>` on your file(s) from the command line, it will tell you exactly where the errors are.